# Performance hit when handling every single event from event-emitters RN?

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance, react-native-reanimated

I am doing my own "swipe to delete component" like react-native-gesture-handler offers. I am not using theirs because it is laggy as hell. It looks great when swiping at a slow pace, but when I flick my finger it stutters like crazy.

Now I am using `onResponderMove()` to update the location of the swipeable View. But now I am asking myself whether or not it is a good idea to process every single event. The event handling looks like this at this moment:

```
  const leftTest = useSharedValue(0);

  const style = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: leftTest.value }],
    };
  });

  const handleMove = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
    if (!firstTouch) {
      startX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
      firstTouch = true;
    }
    const currentX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
    let distX = currentX - startX;
    leftTest.value = distX;

    console.log(leftTest.value);
  };
 
  return 
    <Animated.View 
       onResponderMove={handleMove}
       style={style}
    />
```

I am using `react-native-reanimated`for moving the View by modifying the `translateX` property.

When I throttle the function call to even 10ms it does not look smooth. For fast flicks I can just go without a throttle but with those long drags the event gets emitted like 30 times within a second. For my little human computer science student brain it is crazy to even think about handling such calculations in such a short time, but I know that it is a finger snap for a computer. And since I understand what's going on inside a computer and how it works it should be an easy call to just accept that the computer/phone is able to handle this little work load.

But I am still wondering if such small but many calls are gonna result in a performance drop down and a drain on the battery?? I am also gonna add some more code to that block but it is still going to be a rather simple "just do some math calculations call".

Since I got into CS, almost finished my Bachelors Degree and therefore have a well rounded knowledge on how software and hardware work, I can even less fathom that a computer is that powerful. I just need somebody to tell me that a phone can handle that workload.

Answer (score 0):

Modern smartphones are quite powerful and should be able to handle the workload of processing multiple touch events without any significant performance issues or battery drain.

However, you can try implementing debouncing or throttling to limit the number of event calls.

```js
const handleMove = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
  if (!firstTouch) {
    startX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
    firstTouch = true;
  }
  const currentX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
  const distX = currentX - startX;
  leftTest.value = distX;

  console.log(leftTest.value);
  
  // Throttle the function call with a 100ms delay
  if (!throttleTimeout) {
    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      throttleTimeout = null;
    }, 100);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah that’s what I needed to hear. Yeah I tried both but In this case I need a smooth animation of a finger tracker. So throttling made the animation stutter and feel laggy. But yeah usually always good to throttle or denounce. 
Thanks mate!